# InfluxDB deadman alert disappears from list, but is not deleted

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I have created several deadman alerts and noticed that the last 10 alerts disappeared at once from the alerts list.

The alerts are still active, as the alert notifications are being sent, as configured. In the alert history you can see the triggered alerts, but there is no link to the configurations.

I noticed that when I created an alert with an existing name, an error popped up
(Failed to create check: A check named "test" already exists. Please rename the check before saving) and afterwards the alert disappeared from the list, but was still active as described above.

Is there a way I can see/delete all alerts in the influx client?

What could be the reasons for this problem?
Is it an issue caused by the renaming-overwriting of an alert?
Is there a maximum of alerts in the InfluxDB OSS?

I had the same problem on the influx 2.3 and 2.5 version.

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that they only visibly disappear as there must be something like a limit for "shown" alerts. When I started deleting other alerts, the missing alerts started reappearing...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).